# Retrofit Call enqueue method or Rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

As Retrofit [docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#enqueue-retrofit2.Callback-) represent Call enqueue method in Retrofit is :

> Asynchronously send the request and notify callback of its response or
>   if an error occurred talking to the server, creating the request, or
>   processing the response.

and Rxjava [according to this tutorial](http://randomdotnext.com/retrofit-rxjava/) is  :

> RxJava and RxAndroid libraries allow us to easily do async processing
>   using principles of functional reactive programming

it seems these two have the same approach. What is advantages and disadvantages of each? Which one is better to use?

Comment: Which approach did you end up using?

Comment: I used Retrofit enqueue because I didn't find any reason to use observables but on other project I used Observables because Rx methods was very helpful there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't say they have the same approach. `Retrofit` is specifically designed for API calls which Synchronously or Asynchronously calls an API for you (you can specify that). while `RxJava` & `RxAndroid` can do the similar for you (i.e doing some tasks in sync or async), it is not limited to API call only. You can do many wonders with `RxJava/Android`

As you have quoted that

> `RxJava` and `RxAndroid` libraries allow us to easily do async processing
>   using principles of functional reactive programming

`RxJava` & `RxAndroid` does that with principles of Functional Reactive Programming(FRP). FRP has nothing to do with `Retrofit` & hence they are not same & can't be compared.

You can also use `RxJava/Android` with Retrofit for calling API in FRP Pattern.

Please read [this](http://www.androidauthority.com/reactive-programming-with-rxandroid-711104/) so you can get more idea about FRP:

You should read [this](http://technology.traveltriangle.com/leveraging-the-power-of-rxjava-in-android-apps/) as well for understanding what operators does `RxJava` gives & how you could use them

In the end, if by `Asynchronous` you only meant API calls, then `Retrofit` is better doing that as it's specially designed for that and if by `Asynchronous` you meant some other tasks like resource intensive or so, then obviously `RxJava/Android` will be better if you want async task in FRP pattern like `Observer` or `Observable`.

Comment: Yes, It's true Rxjava is generic and Retrofit Call enqueue is for API call but they have a thing in common and that's async processing. So I guess that's totally comparable. So you say the difference is in Rxjava I'm using FRP pattern and that's all ?

Comment: FRP Pattern is not "That's all". It's really hard to explain what FRP is all about here. You could go through the articles I have linked. While you are focusing more on async processing available on both, it's simple that Retrofit can do Async calls better but it's only limited to API calls, while you could use Rx for doing any resource intensive task asynchronously & notify to all observers. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Which approach is more common for Android devs, which one do you use?

Comment: I use retrofit with RxJava adapter